# Sorting a custom list by year

Tags: c#

I've recently been working with Lists, but I can't seem to find a way of sorting by year in a custom type list. I just can't figure out how to target the year information when sorting my list. Any help will be appreciated.

My code can be viewed below:

```
void Main()
{
    List<DVD> myDVDList = GetFilms();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public List<DVD> GetFilms()
{
    var filmList = new List<DVD>();

    string filename = @"C:\Users\****\Desktop\film-list.txt";
    IEnumerable<string> rawList = File.ReadLines(filename);
    int index = 1;

    foreach(string line in rawList)
    {
        string[] filmInfo = line.Split('*');
        var newDVD = new DVD(index, filmInfo[0], filmInfo[1], int.Parse(filmInfo[2]), filmInfo[3]);
        filmList.Add(newDVD);

        index++;
    }

    return filmList;
}

public class Product
{
    public int IDNumber = 0;
    public string Name = "";
    public int Year = 0;

    public Product(int idNumber, string name, int year)
    {
        IDNumber = idNumber;
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
    }

    public virtual void ProductInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", IDNumber,Name,Year));
    }
}

public class DVD : Product
{
    public string Director = "";
    public string Genre = "";

    public DVD(int idNumber, string name, string director, int year, string genre) : base(idNumber, name, year)
    {
        Director = director;
        Genre = genre;
    }

    public override void ProductInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[DVD - Product Information]: #{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", IDNumber, Name, Director, Genre, Year));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, gb1986, there is some rules to do a good question. Take a look here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/ You must to emphasize a question.

Comment: Thanks for all your solutions to my question. Special thanks to @Felipe Oriani for the link to the article.

Comment: I'm glad to help you @gb1986. if the awnser help you, check it as an awnser to help others with a similar problem to find a solution, and improve your accept rage to get better awnsers in the future. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ on a generic `List<Product>` object:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var orderedList = filmList.OrderBy(z => z.Year).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) or [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
products.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.Year.CompareTo(p2.Year));
```

or (less efficient but more extensible):

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => p.Year).ToList();
```

Note that you don't need to materialize the query to a new list if you don't want to replace the original list with the ordered.

Answer (score 0):

What's this `List` class? I know of `List<T>`, on which you can perform an `OrderBy(film => film.Year)` LINQ expression.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must to type your method to return a `List<DVD>`. Typed objects are good pratices to avoid boxing/unboxing objects.

```
public List<DVD> GetFilms()
{
    ...
}
```

So, you want to show it by sorting a Column, in this case, you can use a lambda expression to set what column you want to order.

```
// remeber to import
using System.Linq;
```

And do something like this:

```
List<DVD> result = GetFilms();

foreach(DVD film in result.OrderBy(f => f.Year))
{
   Console.Write(filme.Name);
}
```

Just as a tip, avoid to call `Console.WriteLine` inside your classes. It is a interface command, and would be nice if you provide a override to `ToString()` method on your DVD class, Product class instead of a method to write it inside your model class.